# Not getting output new to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python.

How do we write this. My out put is not correct.

Programming challenge description:

Write a program which capitalizes the first letter of each word in a sentence.

**Input**: Your program should read lines from standard input. Each line has a sequence of words.

**Output**:  Print the capitalized words.

##### Test 1

###### Test InputDownload Test 1 Input

Hello world

Expected Output:

```
Hello World
```

A Letter

```
import sys
# import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
# from sklearn import ...

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end="")
    line = "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

To capitalize a word use `your_word.capitalize()`

If you need to capitalize each word of a sentence like "Hello world!" you first need to split your sentence in a list of word:

```py
sentence = "Hello world!"
words = sentence.split(" ")
```

Then, Modify the list capitalizing each word.

```py
words = [word.capitalize() for word in words]
```

And finally convert you list back to a string to get the wanted result

```py
result = " ".join(words)
```

For the 2nd example if you just need to capitalize the first word,  instead of using the list comprehension `words = [word.capitalize() for word in words]` you can just mutate the first element of the list, without reassigning it entirely

```py
words[0] = words[0].capitalize()
```

Here is a concrete example using input

```py
def capitalizeSentence(s):
    return " ".join([w.capitalize() for w in s.split(" ")])

inputSentence = input("type a sentence")
print(capitalizeSentence(inputSentence))
```

**EDIT**

As said in the comment below, the `str.title() method that I didn't know, allows you to capitalize each word in a sentence directly:

```py
inputSentence = input("type a sentence")
print(inputSentence.title())
```

Comment: for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end="")
    line = "Hello world"
    words = line.split("")
    words = (word.capitalize() for word in words)
    result = "". join(words)
    break
    words(0) = words (0).capitalize()

Comment: Gives me this error

Comment: Test 1
 Failed
Test Input:
Hello world
Expected Output:
Hello World
Your Output:
(None)
stderr
  File "/tmp/source.py", line 13
    words(0) = words (0).capitalize()
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
Test 2
 Failed
Test Input:
a letter
Expected Output:
A Letter
Your Output:
(None)
stderr
  File "/tmp/source.py", line 13
    words(0) = words (0).capitalize()
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: you are trying to index with parenthesis `words(0)`, it's `words[0]`. (please avoid posting too much code in comments, it's unreadable)

Comment: Instead of running `.capitalize()` on each word in a string, you can just use `sentence.title()` and it will capitalize the first letter of every word.

Comment: @DavidBuck Didn't know that! I added it to the examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version with some comments to help:

```py
# Write a program which capitalizes the first letter of each word in a sentence.


sentance = 'hello and have a nice day'
new_sentance = ''

# split the sentance
words = sentance.split(' ')

# make each first letter uppercase
for word in words:
    new_sentance = new_sentance + ' ' + word.capitalize()



print(new_sentance)
```

result:

```
Hello And Have A Nice Day
```

Comment: I follow what you suggested but still got the out put as " Your Output:
Hello world
  Hello
  Hello World"

Comment: @AyeChanThu how do you mean ?    an example of the input string `hello and have a nice day` is given and the output from this `Hello And Have A Nice Day` is also shown...